# How to delete accidental copy of cache file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, rm

I have a ubuntu server running that uses a windows share (mounted via /etc/fstab). While trying to copy some data to that newly mounted directory I accidentally copied /var/cache too.
Now the problem is that I am not able to delete the copy again.

```
rm -r cache/
rm: das Entfernen von 'cache/apt/archives/cifsbd25' ist nicht möglich: Datei     oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

I think the english transition is ~ can't delete: file or folder not found.
I already ran that command as root. -f did not help either.
I was able to delete everything but this one file. Ho do I get rid of it?

```
ll
insgesamt 3072
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data root   65536 Dez  5 21:42 ./
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data root       0 Dez  5 21:42 ../
-rwxrwx--- 1 www-data root 2586034 Okt 14 16:23 cifsbd25*
```

Comment: Have you ran it with `-f` as root? (At the same time)

Comment: Can you read the file (e.g. `cat cifsbd25 > /dev/null`)? Or you get "file not found" again?

Comment: running rm -f cifsbd25 as root doesn't give an error but also doesn't delete the file. Reading the file gives mit a file not found error.

Comment: In your question the filename ends with a `*` but in the commands you're saying you've entered you've reference it without the `*`, did you forget the `*` or was that a mistake in the question?

Comment: Thats strange. ls gives me cifsbd25 and ll cifsbd25* as a result. Neither seems to work with rm -f though (or do I need to escape something when using the * ?)

Comment: You do need to escape the `*` as `\*`. If you press Tab when you have part of the name it should escape the rest as needed.

Comment: The  /var/cache data was copied to the Windows share, correct?  Are you able to find the file on a Windows host?  If so, can you rename the file to remove the asterisk (*) and all other special characters from a Windows host?  Does that enable you to delete the file, either from your Ubuntu server or from the Windows host?

Comment: It seems like a restart has fixed the problem. Today I restarted the vm for other reasons and when I looked into the folder again to try out your ideas the file was gone and I was able to remove the (now empty) cache copy.

Should I add this as an answer to my own question?

Comment: @CodeO Go ahead! :-D

Answer (score 0):

So in the end a restart fixed my problem (the file was gone). I guess a normal rm command + the restart is the "fix" then.